# Stop all the running software/functions in the background

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am working on a Linux Platform and I want to stop running the software I don't use in that moment, in order to minimize unnecessary workload within my VM(Virtual .

It also takes way to much to open even the terminal or the Files or anything.

Comment: Minor wording improvements.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I guess you saw my input, and well, in order to not carry the -1 around, I will delete it. For you, I recommend that you turn to askubuntu.com, and ask a more specific question there. As said: A) dont use VMs to violate company policies and B) stopping jobs manually is inefficient. Rather selectively install things you need, and de-install stuff you dont need. C) And of course: dont do these things manually, consider using tools like chef, puppet, ... that create VMs based on configuration descriptions for you. Go google "infrastructure as code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal and write down the command:

```
sudo service <your software> stop
```

And whenever you want to start a certain software, type:

```
sudo service <> start
```

or restart:

```
sudo service <> restart
```

or ask for status:

```
sudo service <> status
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It helped me. It wasn t me the one that marked down ur post.